# Dynamically finding @EXPORT and @EXPORT_OK for a loaded module

Tags: perl

I'm writing a script to clean up code which implicitly imports modules. I'd like to change instances of `use Foo;` to `use Foo qw( bar baz );`

In order to automate this, I'd like to be able to know what the contents of `@Foo::EXPORT` and `@Foo::EXPORT_OK` are. I'm trying to do this without using `PPI` to start with.

So, given the variable `$module_name`, how can I access `@EXPORT` and `@EXPORT_OK` for that module?

Comment: Be aware that `@EXPORT` etc is Exporter specific and not all modules use that.  Even if they do, there's no guarantee that it is a static global in the package.  You should inspect them first and set aside any modules that don't define them for manual intervention.  A module's `import` function can do absolutely anything it wants.  That's why you had to do `POSIX->import` in your answer.

Comment: Exporter::Tiny also uses `@EXPORT` and `@EXPORT_OK` but modules can define custom subs that will override their use; Type::Library (used by Types::Standard) does for example.

Comment: I'm also finding this doesn't work with anything that uses `Sub::Exporter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are really asking how you can access a package variable with the name of the package in a variable.

With a "soft" (of "symbolic") reference, you "deference" a string. When Perl sees that's not a reference, it instead uses the package variable it works out from the string value. `strict` disallows this, so you have to turn off that portion of its checks:

```
my $class = 'Foo';
eval "require $class";  # or however you want to load it
my @exports = do {     
    no strict 'refs';
    @{$class . '::' . 'EXPORT'};
    };
```

You've basically done this in your own answers with lots of convenience stuff wrapped around it. `Module::Runtime`, for example, is sanity checking the module name and converting it to a filename that it can `require`. That's fine, but it obscures the meat of your solution.

You mention PPI but not the reason you don't want to use it. For those of you just joining the party, you can't necessarily tell from static analysis what will be in any Perl variable. I deal with some modules that dynamically build up the export list based on what it defines and what will be available based on some other conditions. That is, `@EXPORT` and friends are empty until the end of the unit compilation. That's not something you should do, but it's possible and statically uninspectable.

Comment: Thank you! You've much more clearly expressed my clumsily worded question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Graham Knop for pointing out the syntax I needed and also for a PerlMonks conversation which covers this: [exports -- which module exports are used?](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1054312)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Printer; # exports p()
use Module::Runtime qw( require_module );

my $module_name = 'POSIX';

require_module( $module_name );
$module_name->import;

no strict 'refs';
p @{$module_name.'::EXPORT'};
p @{$module_name.'::EXPORT_OK'};
```

Comment: There is a way of doing it without turning off strictures (i.e. using `%::`), but the way you did it is a how I would recommend it. It's simpler that way, and there's no point in hiding the fact that really are performing a symbolic dereference.

Comment: Note that `$module_name->import` doesn't help you

Comment: @ikegami without the import, the lists come up empty.

Comment: POSIX does it's own thing.  https://metacpan.org/source/XSAWYERX/perl-5.32.0/ext%2FPOSIX%2Flib%2FPOSIX.pm#L250

Comment: Ah, it does. Thank you. At least I have that use case covered now as well. :)